# MariaDb slow_query_log environment variable with Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, dockerfile

is there a way to pass a custom environment var from my dockerfile or docker-compose.yml to my.cnf configuration file?

What i'd like to do is to have the slow_query_log configuration option dinamically set between production and development environment.

I've already tried with different synthax: ${{VAR_NAME}} $VAR_NAME ${VAR_NAME} {{getenv "VAR_NAME"}} but nothing works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using build argument variables and if conditions in my dockerfile.